# What happened to the "Create Link" option when you right-click a file or folder in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, desktop-icons

I used to be able to create links to individual folders and files and put these links on my desktop. After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04, this no longer seems to be the case. Did Ubuntu get rid of the ability to create links? Or is there another way that they want folks to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable it in nautilus preferences:

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. I'm feeling pretty stupid right about now. Blessings. :  )